# Won't book after running sudo apt remove

Tags: boot, apt, boot-repair

I ran the following command trying to backtrack from an install guide which removed the following packages.

```
sudo apt remove python3-dev libcairo2 libcairo-dev python3-cairo libgirepository-1.0-1 libgirepository1.0-dev libcairo-gobject2
```

And now the systems fails to boot. It’s a black screen with,

```
dev/sda1: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks
```

I tried going to `ctrl + alt + f3` terminal and reinstalled those packages (which worked) but still not booting. I also tried boot-repair auto repair but it didn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you haven't provided any output of any of those commands, you're asking us to guess. Output from *all* of those command would go a long way to helping us understand the problem.

Comment: Maybe it was my wording, the commands all worked.  I Updated now to better explain. Cheers

Comment: @Kaigo that doesn't help much .. we need the full output of the `sudo apt remove ...` command, to see what packages has been removed ... even though you off course verified the list of packages it suggested to remove, before pressing "YES" ? Or the relevant part of logfile /var/log/apt/term.log.
One or more of the packages you removed might have had dependencies to the desktop, and removed that.

Comment: @Kaigo, you migth have to reinstall the desktop, like `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` if the first one gives errors.

The desktop package name could be something else depending on what DE you whare using before. But this one will install the default Ubuntu DE.

Comment: @SorenA that worked! It's up and running again. Thanks. Can you make as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or more of the packages you removed might have had dependencies to the desktop, and removed that too. You should always check  the list of packages that apt says it will remove, before saying YES. Look in /var/log/apt/term.log to see the list of what was removed.

You can (re)install the desktop, with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` or `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` if the first one gives errors.

The desktop package name could be something else depending on what DE you where using before. But this one will install the default Ubuntu DE.